# In react-router v4, is it possible to get the deepest route's param out of that Route component

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

My use case is to have a universal page view statistic function for `react-router v4`, so it may looks like:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Tracker>
      <App />
    </Tracker>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

My advanced requirement is to get all params from route, so a URL of `/users/kitty/books/199231` can be parsed to:

```
{
  path: '/users/:username/books/:isbn',
  params: {
    username: 'kitty',
    isbn: '199231'
  }
}
```

The problem is, my `Tracker` component can never get access to a nested route's `path` and `match` prop, even if I use `withRouter` with my `Tracker` component, it gets a path of `/`

I know in theory my requirement is not correct because we can put two or more `<Router>` side by side by side, so my real case would be "get the deepest route's params"

Is it possible to archive this? or is there any solution that my page view statistics can parse a URL to it's corresponding route path and params?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I ended up writing a `TrackRoute` component and replace all **leaf** `<Route>` to `<TrackRoute>`, here is the actual implement: https://github.com/ecomfe/react-track/blob/master/src/components/TrackRoute.js